# How can I refer to the last value input by the user using Scanner?

Tags: java

I'm using a while loop in order to weed out user input of less than 100 and then make them enter values until they satisfy the condition of being >=100.

But once a value >=100 is entered they would have to enter it again for it to be defined, since the while loop executes getLength once and then updating the int length executes getLength a second time.

```
while(getLength.nextInt() < 100) //asks user to enter value to check if its less than 100
  {
     System.out.print("You have entered a value less than 100, please enter a value equal to or greater than 100:\n");
  }
int length = getLength.nextInt(); //this makes the user have to enter it again
```

So instead of outputting:

> ```
> 25  
> You have entered a value less than 100, please enter a value equal to or greater than 100:  
> 50  
> You have entered a value less than 100, please enter a value equal to or greater than 100:  
> 125  //while loop  
> 125  //defining int length
> ```

I want it to have this:

> ```
> 25  
> You have entered a value less than 100, please enter a value equal to or greater than 100:  
> 50  
> You have entered a value less than 100, please enter a value equal to or greater than 100:  
> 125 //prompted by while loop, value is used to define int length
> ```

Essentially, can I get the previously entered user input that was prompted by a while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take an int variable where the user input can be saved.

```
    int x;

    while((x = getLength.nextInt()) < 100 ) 
    {
         System.out.println("You have entered a value less than 100, please enter a value equal to or greater than 100");
    }

    int length = x;
```

By this way you can assign the last value entered to length.